# Fixing the Camera Preview and Picture Quality - Python Kivy to Android APK)

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy

I have an issue with the camera section of my code. I have an app where it allows the user to take photos and save them with a custom filenames. It uses the Kivy framework for the user interface. The app has a camera preview and a "Capture" button to take photos. After capturing an image, the app displays a screen where the user can preview the picture taken. Alongside with the options to accept or retake the photo. The filename is entered by the user in a popup window (first thing you do). The photo is saved to a defined location with the entered filename.

The problem I am having right now is on the Capture screen that the camera preview has black bars around it. I cannot seem to make the app detect the best resolution. Aside of that it won't also adjust with the rotation of the phone. Here is the part of snippet regarding the camera:

```
    def get_filename(self, instance):
        self.filename = self.filename_input.text
        self.filename_popup.dismiss()
        self.show_camera()

    def show_camera(self):
        self.camera = Camera(index=self.camera_index, resolution=(1920, 1080), play=True)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.camera)
        with self.camera.canvas.before:
            self.camera_rotation = Rotate()
            self.camera_rotation.origin = self.camera.center
            self.camera_rotation.angle = 270
            self.camera.bind(size=self.update_rotation_origin, pos=self.update_rotation_origin)
        capture_button = Button(text='Capture', size_hint=(1, 0.2))
        capture_button.bind(on_press=self.capture_image)
        self.layout.add_widget(capture_button)

    def update_rotation_origin(self, *args):
        self.camera_rotation.origin = self.camera.center

    def capture_image(self, *args):
        destination_path = os.path.join(primary_external_storage_path(), 'DCIM', f'{self.filename}.png')
        self.camera.export_to_png(destination_path)
        self.destination_path = destination_path
        self.layout.clear_widgets()
        self.show_image_preview()
```

Help & feedback is appreciated... (I am pretty new to coding)..

Best regards,

I tried manually changing different resolutions but it did not seem to do something the size of the screen. Only thing that improved was stretching the camera preview in the width, meaning there was still empty black space above. I wanted to adjust it to fit the whole screen with the best resolution possible (compatible with other android devices).